# String List OutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

I know this has to be something simple I am overlooking, but it's causing me problems with 2 different classes. They have a similar setup, so I'm just going to post the code for one class. Here is the exact error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
>   Parameter name: length
>      at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
>      at Terminal_Control_Center.UserDir.newDir() in C:\Users\Chris\Documents\GitHub\TerminalControlCenter\Terminal Control Center\Terminal Control Center\UserDir.cs:line 30
>      at Terminal_Control_Center.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Chris\Documents\GitHub\TerminalControlCenter\Terminal Control Center\Terminal Control Center\Program.cs:line 259

```
namespace Terminal_Control_Center
{
    class UserDir
    {
        List<string> userDir;
        string input = "";
        public UserDir(List<String> userDir, string input)
        {
           this.userDir = userDir;
            this.input = input;
        }

        public void newDir()
        {
            // checks for invalid characters
            if (input.Contains("/") || 
                input.Contains(".") || 
                input.Contains(",") || 
                input.Contains("+") || 
                input.Contains("*") || 
                input.Contains("\\") || 
                input.Contains("]") || 
                input.Contains("[") || 
                input.Contains("{") || 
                input.Contains("}") || 
                input.Contains(";") || 
                input.Contains("'") || 
                input.Contains("\"") || 
                input.Contains(":") || 
                input.Contains("<") || 
                input.Contains(">") || 
                input.Contains("%"))
            {
                // use later for invalid input
            }
            else // throws error
            {
                // currently throwing error LINE:30  
                userDir.Add(input.Substring(5, input.Length - 1)); 
            }
        }

        public string getDir()
        {
            return userDir[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had bad commenting. The error occurs at line 30, the substring part. The comment is to throw an error to the user that they input invalid characters.

Comment: Its because `input` length is less than 6

Comment: @gene The input length was 8. I tried a different input "new @testtrial" and, it still throws the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and has a specified length; In your case the start index is given as `5` and the length is given as `input.Length - 1`. Now consider; The input is a sequence of characters of length `15`; then what you are trying to retrieve? a substring that's start index is `5` and are of length `15-1` ie, `14`. So the compiler will trying to take next `14` characters from `5`, But there is nothing after `15th` character. that cause the error ;

More specifically you can define the conditions like the following:

```
  int startIndex = 5; // Will be the start index
  if (input.Length < startIndex || ...)
     {
         // use later for invalid input
     }
  else 
     {
        // This will take all character comes after the specified index(`5`) 
        userDir.Add(input.Substring(5)); 
     }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed.